# Conditionally redefine \big, \bigg, etc. to \left or \right (locally)

Tags: math-mode, macros, conditionals, delimiters

To speed up my typesetting work I'm exploring the possibility to redefine 
some commands "locally".

In this particular case I'd like to redefine the `\big`, `\Big`, etc. commands to the `\left` and `\right` commands. The redefinition must be conditioned by the next-char (or next-regexp).

E.g. something like this "pseudo-code":

```latex
\newcommand{\myRedefinedBigs}{%
  COND 1 next char (or next regexp) is (or "(" "[" "\{")
  \renewcommand{\big}{\left}
  \renewcommand{\Big}{\left}
  \renewcommand{\bigg}{\left}
  \renewcommand{\Bigg}{\left}
  COND 2 next char (or next regexp) is (or ")" "]" "\}")
  \renewcommand{\big}{\right}
  \renewcommand{\Big}{\right}
  \renewcommand{\bigg}{\right}
  \renewcommand{\Bigg}{\right}}
```

The idea is to wrap an equation with this command. E.g.:

```latex
{\myRedefinedBigs
\begin{equation}
\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)
\end{equation}}\relax
```

Can this be made in LaTeX? If so, what do I need to looking for?

**Edit.** [Wermer solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526866/33634) seemed to work but it fails in the case on nested pair of the same kind. E.g.:

```
{\myRedefinedBigs
\begin{equation}
\big(\frac{1}{2}\big(3\)\big)
\end{equation}}\relax
```

[image]

**Note.**

I don't write documents myself from scratch. I prepare the works of scientists to be published in physics journals. So I have to "correct" layout "errors" according to the guidelines provided.

Comment: If one doesn't have to expand stuff in the “argument” of `\myRedefinedBigs` in order to see all occurrences of `\big`, `\Big`, etc.  to replace, `l3regex` can do the job. An environment syntax would probably be cleaner.

Comment: It's probably better (more syntactically appealing) to define a new `equation` environment that does this at the start, rather than using the scoped construction with `\myRedefinedBigs` outside the `equation`.

Comment: I need a more general solution. I need to apply it to every math environment and, eventually, to in line math. In my case a "wrapper" is the best solution.

Comment: What if your document has `\bigl` or `\Bigr`?

Comment: @egreg I know that the solution I'm asking for can't be applied in all cases. But as an experienced typesetter I have an idea of the typesetting style of the most of the authors that I'm dealing with. My idea is to have an emacs lisp function binded to a keyboard key so "curing" an equation should be much faster.

Comment: @egreg I'm talking about equation of known content.

Comment: I would not recommend this approach. Would paired math delimiters from `mathtools`, which take an optional size argument, be a good alternative?

Comment: @Davislor Not in my case. As a  copy-editor I'm searching for a very fast solution. Werner's answer and some emacs-lisp code do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following assumes that you're using `\big` and friends in a paired form, similar to `\left` and `\right`. Also, it assumes opening delimiters are associated with `\left` and closing delimiters with `\right`. Any unmatched `<delim>`iters revert back to `\big<delim>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myRedefinedBigs}{%
  \let\oldbig\big% Copy \big into \oldbig
  \def\big{% Redeine \big
    \@ifnextchar({\biglparen}{% \big is followed by (
    \@ifnextchar){\bigrparen}{% \big is followed by )
    \@ifnextchar[{\biglbracket}{% \big is followed by [
    \@ifnextchar]{\bigrbracket}{% \big is followed by ]
    \@ifnextchar\{{\biglbrace}{% \big is followed by \{
    \@ifnextchar\}{\bigrbrace}{% \big is followed by \}
    \oldbig}}}}}}}% \big is followed by something else, so resort to \oldbig
  \def\biglparen({\left(}% \big( is replaced by \left(
  \def\bigrparen){\right)}% \big) is replaced by \right)
  \def\biglbracket[{\left[}% \big[ is replaced by \left[
  \def\bigrbracket]{\right]}% \big] is replaced by \left]
  \def\biglbrace\{{\left\{}% \big\{ is replaced by \left\{
  \def\bigrbrace\}{\right\}}% \big\} is replaced by \left\}
  \let\Big\big% Handle \Big just like \big
  \let\bigg\big% Handle \bigg just like \big
  \let\Bigg\big% Handle \Bigg just like \big
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
  \big(\frac{1}{2}\big)
\]

{\myRedefinedBigs
\[
  \big(\frac{1}{2}\big)
\]}

\[
  \big(\frac{1}{2}^{\Big\{\frac{1}{2}\Big]}\big)
\]

{\myRedefinedBigs
\[
  \big(\frac{1}{2}^{\Big\{\frac{1}{2}\Big]}\big)
\]}

\[
  \big(\frac{1}{2}\big(3\big)\big)
\]

{\myRedefinedBigs
\[
  \big(\frac{1}{2}\big(3\big)\big)\big|
\]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work in the case of nested `\big`, `\Big`, etc. E.g. in this case: `\big(\frac{1}{2}\big(3\big)\big)`

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi: It does work, but just not the way you want to. How about `\let\bbig\big` and then `\big(\frac{1}{2}\bbig(3\bbig)\big)`?

Comment: Ok, but I'm searching for a solution to speed up my typesetting work. The company I work for has guidelines about brakets so, often, I need to expand them in a lot of equations. Also I have to enlarge `\tfrac` to `\frac` so cases like `\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\big)` need to be cured. I'd trying to build a script (in emacs lisp) to wrap math enviroments. Your solution helps but it's not the complete solution I'm searching for,

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi: True. `\big` captures everything up to the next `\big`. So, in your case, the first two `\big`s are replaced by `\left(`...`\right(`. They both size to the larger `\frac`. Then the final two `\big`s are turned into `\left)\right)`, so they're set as regular parentheses without anything between then to scale it. That's why a replacement of the nested elements with `\bbig` works.

Comment: I understand. But this complacates my work instead of simplify it. I do no typeset document by myself. I prepare scientists' works to be published on physics journals. So I have to "fix" layout "mistakes".

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi: Sorry, try [this definition](https://pastebin.com/raw/AvycXAzf) instead...

Comment: Beautiful! It works! I'll try it for a while and let you know.

Comment: I think I tested your last definition enough to say that it works for my purposes. If you like it, please add it to your answer so that I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi: Updated.

Answer (score 1):

### About the issue

A user is supposed to use *opening* and *closing* delimiters in its formulas. Moreover, you should not redefine a useful macro but use another macro as appropriate.

You can see different delimiters (sizes and shapes) in the following example. You can also see the opening and closing delimiters.

#### Exercice 17.14 (TeXbook)

```
\pi(n)=\sum_{m=2}^n\left\lfloor\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}
  \bigl\lfloor(m/k)\big/\lceil m/k\rceil\bigr\rfloor\biggr)^{-1}
\right\rfloor
```

It is easy to replace opening and closing delimitors in the sample code.

**Important:** `\left` or `\right` followed by a delimiter don't always produce the expected delimiters (typographic aesthetics).

For instance, we can see two formatting of the same formula. The formula *on the right* corresponds to the formatting recommended in the TeXbook while the formula on the left could appear after replacing the corresponding modifiers (`\bigl`, `\biggr`...) by `\left` or `\right` in the above code snippet.

[image: Two formatting of the same formula.]

Moreover, the "modifiers" `\left` and `\right` must appear in the same part of the formula.

### About the solution

It is necessary to replace each "modifier" preceding a delimiter with the appropriate modifier.

These modifiers may be automatically replaced by their matching modifiers. The algorithm to be used does not seem very complicated. Its implementation probably must depend on a *text editor*, obviously not on (La)TeX.

Comment: I already use emacs to do this kind of replacements but it is boring and laborious. I'm trying to speed up my work.

Comment: I know that they are (often) using the wrong macros... but I have guidelines about the layout to follow and I'm trying to use the fastest way to do my work (I wrote "tons" of scripts to  speed up my work and in many cases they are relate with (La)TeX). I think this issue could be easily solved. I will esplore more in detail.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to answer the question...

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi, you'd need to parse the `\Big( ... \Big)` nonsense (find matching pairs) and replace them consistently... not fun, true. But certainly doable in emacs' Lisp. Can't help with that, sorry. Perhaps look for a site of emacs fanatics?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I know how to do these kind of replacements with emacs. I'm one of those "emacs fanatic"! ;-)