# Can I use \@ifnextchar to redefine \big macro to \left or \right?

Tags: brackets

This question is relate to [Conditionally redefine \big, \bigg, etc. to \left or \right (locally)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/526864/33634).

I'd like to redefine the `\big` macro respectively to `\left`, when followed by `(`, `[`, and `\{`, and `\right`, when followed by `)`, `]` and `\}`.

I tried to do it using `\@ifnextchar` but this is far away my LaTeX knowledge.

**Note 1.** I know that things like this are considered bad practice but I'm exploring this possibility with a very specific intention.

**Note 2.**
I don't write documents myself from scratch. I prepare the works of scientists to be published in physics journals. So I have to "correct" layout "errors" according to the guidelines provided.

Comment: If you redefine `\big`, `\bigl`, `\bigr` and similar commands will cease to work.

Comment: @egreg I don't care about it. The rededfinition is meant to be "local" (E.g. on a single equation environment or a portion of text). With emacs I can easily test if in the "region" there are occurrences of these commands (`\bigl`, `\bigr` etc.).

Comment: but `\big` is never supposed to appear in a document, it is just the internal shared code for `\bigl` and `\bigr` so don't you want to redefine `\bigl` and `\bigr` rather than `\big` ? (and if the intention is to make all those scalable not author set sizes, you just need `\let\bigl\left` and `\let\bigr\right` with no lookahaead (although most uses in alignments will then give errors of course)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I typeset about 450 physics paper per year and I can assure you than only a 10% of the scientists has a proper knowledge of LaTeX. Most of them uses `\big`, `\Big` and similar. If you don't believe me, take a look at the LaTeX code of the documents on https://arxiv.org/.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Replacing `\big` with `\left` and `\right` is not the solution, I'm afraid; you trade bad typesetting for ugly typesetting.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi sure but if you are asking whether it's safe to use `\@ifnextchar` to redefine invalid markup to be a tex primitive that can only be used in very restricted contexts, then not sure what answer can be other than "no". A primary use for \big (or better bigl  \bigr)  is when the left and right are in different groups, eg different cells in an AMS `align`  using `\left` \right there will fail anyway so how to answer your question if you can use `\@ifnextchar` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand but still you can't imagine how useful would be (for me) in some "particular" cases. This solution is not meant to be used sistematically. Please, believe me, I know what I'm asking for.

Comment: sure you know what you are asking for but the question isn't clear enough to answer sorry, I can't think of any definition along the lines suggested that will not generate errors in many uses of `\big` so I'd say the answer to the question  in the title is "no". If you can cut the question down to massively restricted cases where it may possibly be safe then perhaps an answer other than "no" is possible, but I don't see that yet, and in such a case simply editing the file to have `\left` \right` would be safer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hope I've clarified my question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527579/33634

Comment: er yes but why a new question rather than edit this one? Do you want to close this one now?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think that they are two different questions. In the other one I just asked if it's a bad idea to do what I'm asking for here.

Comment: ok so the answer to this one is "no (in general)" and the answer to the other one is "yes"  but `\let\oldbig\big \def\big#1\ifx(#1\left\else\ifx[#1\left\else\ifx)\right\else\ifx]\right\else\afterffffi\oldbig\fi\fi\fi\fi}   \def\afterffffi#1\f\fi\fi\fi{\fi\fi\fi\fi#1}` probably works in some small fraction of cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104223/discussion-between-gabriele-nicolardi-and-david-carlisle).