# Redefining \big, \Big etc. to \left and \right locally, A (quasi) real case example

Tags: brackets

Lets say I'm reviewing the layout of a paper (I'm not the author) and I have this code:

```latex
\begin{align}
  \Delta_s^-
  &= \frac{|t_s|^2}{2U} \int_{\vec k} \frac{1 }{\omega_U^2}
 \Bigg[\frac{ h_s(\omega_U)}{\Delta_U} + ...\Bigg]
\Big(1- \frac{|t_s|^2}{4\omega_U^2\Delta_U^2} + ... \Big) \, ,
\nonumber \\
\Delta_t^-
  &= \frac{|t_t|^2}{2U}\int_{\vec k} \frac{1 }{\omega_U^2}
 \Big[\frac{ h_t(\omega_U) (s_U^2+\Delta_U^2)}{\Delta_U} + ... \Big]
    \Big(1-\frac{|t_t|^2 (s_U^2+\Delta_U^2)}{8\omega_U^2\Delta_U^2} + ... \Big) \, ,
\end{align}
```

that produces:

[image]

Now, in my typesetting work I have guidelines to follow and one of this is to make brackets fit their content's height.

One thing that I can do is to replace `\[bB]ig*` macros with `\left` and `\right`:

```latex
\begin{align}
  \Delta_s^-
  &= \frac{|t_s|^2}{2U} \int_{\vec k} \frac{1 }{\omega_U^2}1
 \left[\frac{ h_s(\omega_U)}{\Delta_U} + ...\right]
\left(1- \frac{|t_s|^2}{4\omega_U^2\Delta_U^2} + ... \right) \, ,
\nonumber \\
\Delta_t^-
  &= \frac{|t_t|^2}{2U}\int_{\vec k} \frac{1 }{\omega_U^2}
 \left[\frac{ h_t(\omega_U) (s_U^2+\Delta_U^2)}{\Delta_U} + ... \right]
    \left(1-\frac{|t_t|^2 (s_U^2+\Delta_U^2)}{8\omega_U^2\Delta_U^2} + ... \right) \, ,
\end{align}
```

having:

[image]

Another idea (faster for me), is to "wrap" the code with a macro that redefine, for a portion of code, `\[bB]ig*`s to `\left` and `\right`.

Something like:

```latex
{\BigsToLeftRight%
\begin{align}
  \Delta_s^-
  &= \frac{|t_s|^2}{2U} \int_{\vec k} \frac{1 }{\omega_U^2}
 \Bigg[\frac{ h_s(\omega_U)}{\Delta_U} + ...\Bigg]
\Big(1- \frac{|t_s|^2}{4\omega_U^2\Delta_U^2} + ... \Big) \, ,
\nonumber \\
\Delta_t^-
  &= \frac{|t_t|^2}{2U}\int_{\vec k} \frac{1 }{\omega_U^2}
 \Big[\frac{ h_t(\omega_U) (s_U^2+\Delta_U^2)}{\Delta_U} + ... \Big]
    \Big(1-\frac{|t_t|^2 (s_U^2+\Delta_U^2)}{8\omega_U^2\Delta_U^2} + ... \Big) \, ,
\end{align}}\relax
```

Se also my previous questions:

[Conditionally redefine \big, \bigg, etc. to \left or \right (locally)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/526864/33634)

and

[Can I use \@ifnextchar to redefine \big macro to \left or \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527539/33634)

My question is: *why some of the you think that this would be "ugly typesetting"? Would this solution be really so bad?*

Comment: Two-story fractions in display math mode are essentially the only case where `\left` and `\right` actually work well. The particular author seems to like being inconsistent. I sympathize with you, but my opinion is that indiscriminately using `\left` and `\right` may lead to even worse typesetting. By the way, `...` should be changed into `\dotsb` all around in that formula. The equation number should be midway, because it refers to *both* formulas. Since you have to examine each equation anyway, in the long run you lose more time looking for automation instead of just fixing the bad input.

Comment: And, in the particular formula, `\Big` size should be considered.

Comment: and what would you do in the common case that there is a `&` or `\\ ` between the `\bigl[` and `\bigr]`  `\left` and `\right` would error. Since you have to check for those before doing the redefinition it is simpler not to redefine and just (perhaps) change some of them to `\left` and `\right` after checking that is safe

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would not use this solution. But in most of the case I know I could.

Comment: @egreg It isn't my intention to use this solution "indiscriminately".